# ASP.NET MVC UrlHelper.Action() not returning correct path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm having a problem trying to use the `UrlHelper` `Action()` method to point to the `/Home/Index` action on my site. I need to generate links to `Index` dynamically (including an `id` parameter) in client-side script, so I did the obvious:

```
var url = '@this.Url.Action("Index", "Home")';
function generateLink ( id ) {
  var anchor = "<a href='" + url + "/" + id + "'>Select Me</a>"
  return anchor;
}
```

But the anchor tags being generated here look like this:

```
<a href='http://localhost//1013'>Select Me</a>
```

which obviously doesn't route to the correct action. I'm assuming that `Url.Action()` is being "smart" by figuring out that `Home` and `Index` are the default values for my default route, so `http://localhost` and `http://localhost/Home` and `http://localhost/Home/Index` are functionally identical, but I need to somehow force it to pick the full URL option.

Is there a way to do this, or am I going to have to build the URL up myself?

EDIT:

I haven't change the routing from the defaults for a new MVC3 project:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes ( RouteCollection routes )
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new
        {
            controller = "Home",
            action = "Index",
            id = UrlParameter.Optional
        } // Parameter defaults
    );
}
```

ANSWER:

I finally went with a slight variation of @BFree's answer, just because I prefer Html.ActionLink() to Url.Action if I can use it:

```
var anchor = '@this.Html.ActionLink("Select Me", "Index", "Home", new { id = "XXX" }, null)';

function generateLink ( id ) {
  return anchor.replace("XXX", id);
}
```

Comment: We'll need to see the route definitions (all of them, preferably), so we can see if there is a conflict or if there are parameters for the route you are not specifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One hacky approach is to do something like this:

```
var url = '@this.Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { id = 1})';
function generateLink ( id ) {
  var anchor = "<a href='" + url.replace("1",id) + "'>Select Me</a>"
  return anchor;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that works, though I don't like it. If nothing better comes along I'll mark this as the answer. (I don't like it mostly because the URLs look odd:  "http://localhost/?id=1013"

Comment: +1 Actually not hacky I don't think. Perhaps `new { id = "_placeholder_" }` would be better though. Short of having a web service I can't see much other way.

Comment: @Michael: Using my approach, it outputs the full url e.g. :/Home/Index/12345

Comment: Yah, you're right. After casper's comment I started messing around with my routes and I broke routing :) Your answer is what I went with, mostly.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround could be:

```
function generateLink ( id ) {
  var anchor = "<a href='/?id=" + id + "'>Select Me</a>"
  return anchor;
}
```